# How to update Table Rows in a Table?

Tags: android, textview, tableview

I created a static table of 10 rows with four columns with TextView.

Now I need to update/delete the table view as per data change.. how could I do this?

Please give me a precise idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the TextViews inside the TableRow, just use findViewById().
If you want to change a whole TableRow, also use findViewById(), but this time for the TableRow. Now you can use something like addView() and removeView() or removeAllViews().

Comment: Hi I gotta solution for deleting the TableRow,

TableRow.setVisibility(View.GONE); This helps me to completely undraw the table row as not exist.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Thanks for supporting answers

Answer (score 0):

as you say your table is static means 10 rows and 4 columns

Now if want to update value in table then u know the every TextView by Id and directly call `setText("...") ;` method of textview

if you want to delete the row then in that row how many textviews are present set there visibility to invisible or gone

Thanks.

But I suggest that use Table layout use here is best example 
    http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Thanks

Comment: Hi I gotta solution for deleting the TableRow,

TableRow.setVisibility(View.GONE); This helps me to completely undraw the table row as not exist.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Thanks for supporting answers